# Extract number of products from a supermarket webpage depending on postcode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to extract the number of products available on this webpage:

https://www.sklavenitis.gr/eidi-artozacharoplasteioy/keik-tsoyrekia-kroyasan/

I have code using `Scrapy` which does manage to do it.

My problem is that the information displayed depends on the region assumed by the website which shows as HubID in the cookie. Manually, it was possible to change the ID in developer tools, now I want this automated.

Using selenium, I tried to go to the initial page for the supermarket and follow what a user would do: insert a postcode, and follow the steps until I arrive at the page which contains the information I’m after. I managed to write the postcode in the text box, but couldn’t select the item in the drop-down list generated dynamically. I’m also not certain this is the best way to do it. The initial page is:

https://www.sklavenitis.gr

I’d be thankful for any pointers as to a good way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlow! Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow, or it may be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the `cookies` parameter in the request object. Check out it here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects

By using this, you don't need to rely on selenium. You can set the cookie directly in your request, with the value you want.

Hope this helps :)